# I'm having trouble understanding what's wrong with my linking to the include folder of spdlog in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, spdlog

I'm following The Cherno's series on Youtube and in the Logging episode he uses SPDLOG for a log of the actual Game Engine. He uses the `#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"` function to call the `spdlog.h` file into `Log.h` but I keep getting the error saying that it cannot access `spdlog/spdlog.h`

> C:\Users\peyton\source\repos\Hazel2\Hazel\Hazel\src\Hazel\Log.h(5,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'spdlog': No such file or directory

```
//Log.h
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include "Core.h"
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"

namespace Hazel {
    class HAZEL_API Log
    {
    public:
        static void Init();

        inline static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& GetCoreLogger() { return s_CoreLogger; }
        inline static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& GetClientLogger() { return s_ClientLogger; }
    private:
        static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> s_CoreLogger;
        static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> s_ClientLogger;
    };
}
```

This is my code for the Log.h file if it helps.
Also here's the file path for the spdlog folder and its include foler: C:\Users\peyton\source\repos\Hazel2\Hazel\Hazel\src\Hazel\vendor\spdlog-1.x\include
[What my linking looks like for the Addition Include Libraries incase maybe I did something wrong there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHwts.png)

I've already tried to relink the files and I've gone around to many different forums to see if other people have has this issue before. I'm kind of stuck and cant progress without getting past this problem. If someone could help me that would be great.

Comment: What's the EXACT error you're getting, copy and pasted? You're using the term "linking" many times, but the image you show of the include is for Include directories, not link directories; and you also say it cannot "access" the file, which again implies including, which is nothing to do with linking.

Comment: That's unlikely a linker error, you rather missed to specify the path for finding the include files in your project.

Comment: You added `...\include\spdlog` to the include path, which means your compiler will search for `...\include\spdlog\spdlog\spdlog.h`. Are you sure you did not mean to add just `...\include`?

Comment: You write that your include path contains `C:\Users\peyton\source\repos\Hazel2\Hazel\Hazel\src\Hazel\vendor\spdlog-1.x\include`, but from the screenshot we see there is `$(SolutionDir)Hazel\vendor\spdlog-1.x\include\spdlog` instead. Just remove the trailing `spdlog`. Otherwise, you need to `#include "spdlog.h"` instead of `#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"`.

Comment: @peyton _"I'm following The Cherno's series on Youtube"_ Stop watching bad YouTube courses for learning c++. You'll miss many basics, which are better learned from [good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?r=Saves_AllUserSaves).

Comment: @ChrisMM the output error: 1>C:\Users\peyton\source\repos\Hazel2\Hazel\Hazel\src\Hazel\Log.h(5,10): fatal  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'spdlog': No such file or directory

Comment: Either use #include "spdlog.h" or remove the trailing spdlog from the Additional Include Directories setting.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot: `xxx\include\spdlog`

```
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
```

It means the compiler is looking for the xxx\include\spdlog\spdlog\spdlog.h file. Do you really have a file with such a path?

Please try adding additiaoinal include directory  `C：\Users\peyton\source\repos\Hazel2\Hazel\Hazel\src\Hazel\vendor\spdlog-1.x\include`